# How can I ignore some directories in Doxygen?

Tags: c++, c, doxygen, doxygen-wizard, doxywizard

I tried Doxygen to see how it documents a code.
The big problem I encountered is that it scans all the subdirectories, however I need to **avoid some of them because not needed** in the final documentation (they are also inappropriate because not direct parts of my work).
I think it's possible from the Expert tab of the Doxygen's wizard, but I'm a newbie and I don't understand how to set them.
Finally, what happens to the references to the directories excluded (i.e. references to functions, variables, etc...)?

Comment: Which doxygen version? Did you explicitly set `INPUT` or did you have a look at `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS`?

Comment: Version `1.9.2`, and no, I didn't set it because I don't know where I can find them.

Comment: You can find it in the Expert tab>Topics(on the left)>Input scroll a bit. Ta da! add undesired files/directories/extensions to `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS`

Comment: The information can be found in the manual (https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/index.html specifically: https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html and https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_exclude_patterns), ialso with the move over of the items in the expert tab in the doxywizard.

Comment: Right! I found the option! I think that the links you gave to me together are a good starting point